# Java: How to split a String into two separate arrays after a space?

Tags: java

If a client wants to store a message into a txt file, user uses keyword msgstore followed by a quote.

Example: 
`msgstore` "ABC is as easy as 123"

I'm trying to split msgstore and the quote as two separate elements in an array.

What I currently have is:

```
String [] splitAdd = userInput.split(" ", 7);
```

but the problem I face is that it splits again after the second space so that it's:

```
splitAdd[0] = msgstore
splitAdd[1] = "ABC
splitAdd[2] = is
```

My question is, how do I combine the second half into a single array with an unknown length of elements so that it's:

```
splitAdd[0] = msgstore
splitAdd[1] = "ABC is as easy as 123"
```

I'm new to java, but I know it's easy to do in python with something like (7::).

Any advice?

Comment: The Properties class is designed for this use-case however it wants you to format your 'messages' as follows:
msgname=the message you want to associate with this property name.
If you are open to formatting your messages in this way, simply place them in a text file, and then use the load method. Here's a link to some useful documentation https://www.baeldung.com/java-properties

Comment: Your Python example doesn't seem to do a split string on space, it seems to apply a substring. Maybe you're just looking for `userInput.substring(9)` instead? (the equivalent of python`userInput[9:]`)?

Answer (score 1):

substring on the first indexOf `"`

```
String str = "msgstore \"ABC is as easy as 123\"";

int ind = str.indexOf(" \"");

System.out.println(str.substring(0, ind));
System.out.println(str.substring(ind));
```

**edit**

If these values need to be in an array, then

```
String[] arr = { str.substring(0, ind), str.substring(ind)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have `limit` parameter as `7` when you want just 2 elements? Try changing it to `2`:-

```
String splitAdd[] = s.split(" ", 2);
```

OR

```
String splitAdd[] = new String[]{"msgstore", s.split("^msgstore ")[1]};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI6dCl/1)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<quote>[^\"]*)\"(?<message>[^\"]+)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("msgstore \"ABC is as easy as 123\"");

if(matcher.matches()) {
    String quote = matcher.group("quote").trim();
    String message = matcher.group("message").trim();
    String[] arr = {quote, message};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

This is more readable than substring a string, but it definetely slower. As alternative, you can use substirng a string:

```
String str = "msgstore \"ABC is as easy as 123\"";
int pos = str.indexOf('\"');
String quote = str.substring(0, pos).trim();
String message = str.substring(pos + 1, str.lastIndexOf('\"')).trim();
String[] arr = { quote, message };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```